# OpenGL ES 1.1 - texture and alpha and color key

Tags: opengl-es

Using OpenGL ES 1.1.

The picture I am generating is being color-keyed later on down the line.  It replaces one color (magenta) with something else.

So I clean the background with that color, draw on top of it, and everything is good.

However, textures with an alpha channel cause some complications.   I effectively want to use only maximum or minimum alpha, and show the background OR show the image blended with, say, black.

My mostly-working hack has the texture data manually adjusted force the alpha channel to either min or max, and do pre-multiplication for the actual color value, and this mostly works.

However, when the texture size changes, I get a little bit of filtering and some magenta goes through.

So:
1) Is there some combination of glBlendFunc and glTexEnv combiner functions that will let me stop manually editing the textures?
or, failing that....
2) What parameters should I use when drawing the texture to keep alpha at either 0 or 1 when it's scaling?

Answer (score 1):

Use *alpha testing* instead of *blending*. Use [glAlphaFunc](http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/1.1/docs/man/glAlphaFunc.xml) to select a comparision function and reference value. Enable with `glEnable(GL_ALPHA_TEST)` (and disable once you no longer need it during rendering).